# Android - Isn't Eclipse WYSIWYG?

Tags: android

i have downloaded Eclipse Galileo and install Android SDK for the first time.

I have try to create an simple Userinterface, but i have see that i can't move
the "object" directly from the stage. But i need to edit the Code or open the Property panel
in order to change the position of an Element on the Stage.

Isn't Eclipse WYSIWYG?

D.

Comment: Where I work, we use IntelliJ IDEA. It's fairly [WYSIWYG](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse editor is not fully WYSIWYG, it's somewhat limited. There's another tool out at http://www.droiddraw.org/ but I wouldn't recommend to use either.
I find, in the end it's easier and faster to build the UI yourself in xml code (due to lack of really good tools). It's worth the time to study the layout managers in-depth therefore.

Comment: DroidDraw hasn't been updated in a long time and doesn't support tabs.

Answer (score 0):

When you develop the interface for Android in XML, think like you are coding plain HTML and will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Titanium to build your interface

www.appcelerator.com

Comment: The HTML/CSS has gone from appcelerator making it much less WYSIWYG - http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/71/what-happened-to-html--css.  There is always http://PhoneGap.com

Answer (score 0):

Another IDE, but i think only for Motorola - Android.

http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/